# C++: Debug assertion failed (str != NULL)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

In visual studios, when I run "Start without Debugging" I get the error code "Debug assertion failed! Program... file ... line 57". It says "Expression (str!=NULL). I have no idea why this is happening. I read through other questions similar to this and I have made sure that the permissions on the files are correct and that the files do exist.

```
FILE *file_i = fopen("DataMiner_AECO_Tab.txt", "r");
FILE *file_o = fopen("DataMiner_AECO_output.txt", "w");

char line[350];
fgets(line,sizeof line, file_i);
fprintf(file_o, "Data\n");
printf("Data\n");


do {
    fgets(line, sizeof line, file_i);

    float hour[25] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    sscanf(line, "%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", date, &hour[0], &hour[1], &hour[2], &hour[3], &hour[4], &hour[5], &hour[6], &hour[7], &hour[8], &hour[9], &hour[10], &hour[11], &hour[12], &hour[13], &hour[14], &hour[15], &hour[16], &hour[17], &hour[18], &hour[19], &hour[20], &hour[21], &hour[22], &hour[23], &hour[24]);
```

That is lines 42-55. Line 56 is a blank line and lines 57-61 are comments. So I'm guessing that the error is occurring here. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked file_i (and file_o) to see if they are non-NULL?  Most likely one or both files failed to be opened, fopen() returned NULL, and now your fgets() (or fprintf) call is dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Are you sure the assertion is in this file? It is probably on line 57 of some file provided by microsoft.

Comment: If you don't know why your program is failing, "Start without debugging" is clearly not the right thing to do.

Comment: Are you sure this is c++? Looks like C.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner How would I check the files to see if they are non_NULL?

Comment: Why didn't you do any error checking?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have only started programming last month and am not sure how to do most things like error checking of checking if one/both of the files is non-NULL. How do I preform an error check?

Comment: @TNA This program was originally written in C and my professor wanted me to rework it for use in C++.

Comment: Start by reading the docs. They explain how errors are signaled. You aren't really writing C++ yet. Do you know how to debug yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not know how to debug yet and what docs are you talking about reading?

Comment: The docs for the functions you call. You can't hope for success without reading the docs. And you do need to learn to debug.

Comment: @fasick if (file_i == NULL) printf("Oops, file open failed!\n");